# I need an efficient shared dictionary in a Python multiprocessing environment

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have implemented one-producer-multiple-consumer pattern using Python's multiprocessing package. The consumers should put the results in a dictionary. The keys of this dictionary are words and the values are  big Scipy sparse matrix. Each consumer adds its value for each word it sees to the main vector for that word in the shared dictionary.

I have used Manager.dict() to implement this shared dictionary but it is very slow. cpu-utilization is about 15% for each process and it is just a little bit better than a single process.
Each consumer fetches an item from the shared dictionary, adds a sparse matrix to the value of that item and updates the item in the shared dictionary.

Is there any more efficient solution?

Comment: `memcache` - http://memcached.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import memcache

memc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1);
memc.set('top10candytypes', {1 : 2, "3" : [4,5,6]})

bestCandy = memc.get('top10candytypes')
print(bestCandy)
```

I'm no expert on memcache because i've just started to use it myself. But it's handy as hell if you have multiple threads needing to access the same data or if you simply need to store things efficiently without running out of ram.

Comment: how to use memcache: just sudo apt-get install memcached to install memcache server and then pip install python-memcached to install memcache python client.

Comment: The problem is that my words (keys) are unicode but this python memcache client doesn't accept unicode strings in python.

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to overcome the the unicode problem by using another encoding for the strings (UTF-8?). I am sceptical as to whether memcache is going to be any quicker than python multiprocessing Manager for this use case. Does anyone have benchmarks? I am curious as I have done similar stuff and the only fast solution I found was to use shared memory with Multiprocessing Arrays but this felt quite messy.

Comment: yea doing `yourstring.decode('utf-8')` should be enough, altho I really don't get why that would be a problem because what Python does is using cPickle in order to store the variables in its original object form, there for you could theoreticly memcache a class object and return it as it were before stored. Or you could JSON-ify the data before or alter this neat code snippet to do the unicode converting prior to storing the data: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578011-json-instead-of-pickle-for-memcached/ memcache is the fastest storing system there is except for raw variables in memory.

Comment: Anything stored in memory within the application will obviously be a lot quicker, however if you're working with large data-sets memcache will have a huge advantage. Also, sharing things across threads will utelize locks and other mechanisms to overcome deadlocks, corrupt data etc.. Something you won't have to bother with using memcache as it solves these isssues internally and in a extremely efficient manner.

Comment: Yes, threading would be much better if Python didn't have this GIL. I think i'm going to write it in Java. It is a simple multithreaded program but in Python you have to do it using multiprocessing.

Comment: Yea good code needs work, better switch to a language where you don't have to think? :) There's tons of solutions, one of them being http://www.parallelpython.com/ if you really need more juice.. But at the end of the day, you don't even need multiple cores to achieve good results for the most part.

Comment: I think if i'm going to implement such a thing in Python it is better to implement it using a MapReduce like design. So each process builds its own dictionary and after the end we should merge these dictionaries together. I don't know. This design is what i prefer or i have to go to a Java multithreaded implementation.

Comment: I'd love to benchmark these different theories because I personally think either a shared dictionary or as you sad, individual dictionaries will be efficient as hell.
What i normally do (haters gona hate) is i create a dictionary in my main application, send that into my (thread)class and let the thread update `dict['myThread'][...]` only the relevant branch of that dict. Thus having all the data accessible at all times without crashing other threads. The main loop can interact/read the data on the fly. And merge it later on if need be.

Comment: @Torxed I think your dictionary solution is fine but only works with Threads not Processes (unless you use a Manager). Another multiprocessing pattern I often use is to have main thread allocate work via one Queue and collect results from another Queue, so that the dictionary only gets assembled in the main thread. This is slow when you start passing large amounts of data but then if that is the case then your stuff is probably bounded as much by cache as CPU cycles. In these cases, as you say, optimization probably needs to be done at a lower level eg with Cython / openMP

Comment: I am processing English Widipedia, i tried indivisual dictionaries to pickle them and merge them later but it used all the memory. Manager dictionaries are hell slow and i guess memcache wont be faster if not slower. Using a result queue wont help because it will certainly fill the memory. So either i have to use Java with a shared dictionary and locks or try a MapReduce implementation like Hadoop, Spark, etc.

Comment: @user956730 Sounds like exactly the kind of task that MapReduce was designed for!

Comment: @JohnGreenall Yes, Memcache and Manager's dicts are hell slow. There is no cure for that. Either you have to use MapReduce or use a programming language that supports multithreading (e.g. Java, C, C#). It is quite a drawback that in Python you can't share a dictionary between processes.

Comment: @Torxed As JohnGreenall told sharing dictionaries is not possible in multiprocessing module. And Python's multithreading is not a good approach while you have GIL there.

Comment: @user956730 Yepp i'm aware, that's why i mentioned thread just to clairify. But reading my comment again i guess it was more of a story then helping so i apolegize :)

Comment: @user956730 Realize this is a bit late but I just came across joblib today and thought it provided some interesting suggestions to solve the problems we were discussing - in particular writing Cython functions with no_gil flag and mmapping large arrays on disk to share between processes: https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html

Comment: @JohnGreenall Although i have implemented my program and it works well (used Java Multithreading) i will give a try to this no_gil flag for my future implementations. It seems promising.